# Detecting What Module Was Imported As

Tags: python, module, python-import

Is there a way for a Python module to know what a user has imported it as?

For example, if the user does `import myModule as foo`, is there a way for code in `myModule` to know that the user import it as `foo`?

Answer (score 5):

Nope. Python doesn't keep track of what names a module was imported by. Even if it did, a module can be imported by many names over the course of a program, but its code will only be executed on the first import, so it wouldn't get a chance to do anything about the new names.

I suppose if you want, you could *tell* it about the name:

```
# In mymodule
def register_name(name):
    do_something_about(name)

# At the import site
import mymodule as foo
foo.register_name('foo')
```

Kind of unwieldy, though.

Comment: Speaking of unwieldy, you _could_ use an elaborate combination of ```hasattr()``` and ```sys.modules``` to build a structure which would keep track of it.  But you'd have to have an attribute to test for each module you'd expect to have and even having such a correlation probably wouldn't be worth the effort of making it